# css rules not applied when page load

Tags: css

I am new to CSS. I am observing a strange CSS behaviour where an element has the below CSS property

```
.container .header{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 21%;
}
```

When the page loads on Mozilla and chrome, the top property is not applied but inspecting the firebug shows the property. When I edit in firebug just by 1px, the elements gets properly aligned and even if I set the top value to 21% after that, the position is correct. Only on load the CSS property is not applied. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean edit by just 1px? Do you mean you change the css from top: 21% to top: 1px and then reload the page? Is your css external or on the page that loads (whether in the head section or inline)?

Comment: 1) Is your `<style>` tag defined? `<style type="text/css">` Also here is an odd question... 2) before your style tag, do you have a `<TITLE>Title Here</TITLE>` tag? Once i had a weird issue where i could run styles either... The other thing it could be is your `<head>` tag.

Comment: I have an answer for you which i have posted. @user883561

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what it is now. Its your style class names themselves. After much testing I have discovered:

```
.container, .header {
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:5px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top:21%;
}
```

Notice what's after the .container? A COMMA. You need a Comma after every class name that inherits those same attributes! Hope this helped!

Comment: You DONT need a Comma after every style!

Comment: Oh you're right, its every classname, thanks for catching that @pjp

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calculating the `top` value in percentages and to make that happen, you need a declared height for it's parent i.e. `container`.

```
.container, body, html {
    height:100%;
}
```

Add the rule above and see it working. [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2p7nM/)

**NOTE -** `body` and `html` also need their height declared(either in percentages or pixels) too as container's parent is `body` and like so.